# Retrieve data using token authentication

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, authentication

I'm really new in this side of development, my co-worker gave me this information. to retrieve the database. I'm not really sure what to do with it.

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Token token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "https://www.example.com/api/transactables?page=1&per_page=1"
```

can you please point me to the right direction here?

is there a standard code format that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can use the `headers` property of `$.ajax` to add your token. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: 'https://www.example.com/api/transactables',
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Token token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  },
  data: {
    page: 1,
    per_page:1
  },
  success: function (){
    console.log('success!');
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Rory, thank you for trying to help, I tried your suggestions but I'm receiving a 404 error.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.example.com.au/api/transactables?page=1&per_page=10. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Comment: By the way what's the use of  "curl -X GET -H "Authorization" ?